# Passing ref to a textInput wrapped in a component

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-typescript

I have 6 TextInputs and I am trying to switch through all of them (switching focus) when pressing the submit button on the keyboard. I have a functional component that uses a TextInput from react-native-paper inside of it. I want to pass a ref as prop when using this component. Unfortunately, I don´t know how.

My Component:

```
type ParticipantProps = {
    placeholder: React.ReactNode
    onChangeText: (text: string) => void
    ref: React.MutableRefObject<typeof TextInput> //This type is wrong
} 

export default function ParticipantInput({ placeholder, onChangeText, ref }: ParticipantProps) {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");

    const formatUserName = (textValue: string): string => {
        var upperCase: string = textValue.toUpperCase()
        setName(upperCase);
        return upperCase;
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <Text>{placeholder}</Text>
            <TextInput
                ref={ref}
                value={name}
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                    onChangeText(formatUserName(text));
                }}
                maxLength={2}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize='characters'
                style={styles.textInput}
                underlineColor={Colors.secondary}
                activeUnderlineColor={Colors.secondary}
                theme={{ colors: { text: Colors.tint } }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Where I want to use it:

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
    <ParticipantInput placeholder='Spieler 1' onChangeText={(name) => setPlayer(players.set(1, name))} />
    <ParticipantInput placeholder='Spieler 2' onChangeText={(name) => setPlayer(players.set(2, name))} />
    <ParticipantInput placeholder='Spieler 3' onChangeText={(name) => setPlayer(players.set(3, name))} />
    <ParticipantInput placeholder='Spieler 4' onChangeText={(name) => setPlayer(players.set(4, name))} />
    <ParticipantInput placeholder='Spieler 5' onChangeText={(name) => setPlayer(players.set(5, name))} />
    <ParticipantInput placeholder='Spieler 6' onChangeText={(name) => setPlayer(players.set(6, name))} />
</View>
```

First of all, I dont know what type I have to give the ref prop.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components). `ref` is a special property you can't use just in the normal way. Instead, with a function component, you wrap the component using [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref), and then receive the ref as a second argument to your function component:

```
    export default React.forwardRef(function ParticipantInput({ placeholder, onChangeText }: ParticipantProps, ref) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
        // ...
    });
// −−^^
```

The type of the `ref` you receive is apparently a bit of a pain, see [this issue](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1453#issuecomment-699163546). This seems to work though:

```typescript
import { TextInput as RNTextInput } from "react-native";
// ...
export default React.forwardRef(function ParticipantInput({ placeholder, onChangeText }: ParticipantProps, ref: ForwardedRef<RNTextInput>) {
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQEwewOwOQBdo1AJQKYEMDGKA5bJASwDdMAaUAZzSQAsSbQAzEgJxpRIFsAHGBxS9sAT1BwYKAEaZQARwCuJJPNxCOmfACg+g4Rhz5qAb1BKamAMpJiVUADEhAd2wcomKFlagAvmwcMLygAERaeEihANx6AkIo5gAqmAAeSOBw-Eoo2CzoBCnpmdkoAaxBIQgR+AC0cMTkmAix+gmgyWlI1EUZWTn+gcFhNUj1jRS1-Nj8mBwxOjogoAAKADZ4mAwwa54cOhpw3KAAaiSYLqAAvKAAFKa4TLtacH4AXKDYcGIAlNcAfKAADxQcj-B5PKAvPxA4Cgsj-WI6JBiWardykXAkaZwJArIL8Fg3Uw6UBk0D8Da4LY7PYfLCRAB0DPwBBgnlJ5PgAGEGF8AOaYXofW5qdIfbgcEhwfl-K6AsgwEhQTlkrSsenGJCMgCyOWwMjWmB8AHkZAArbRIIEo2YwXy9Eo5QEgJJMFi2+TMUAuIIynQBJYAKjSBhQnlY2CUayQQeAh2OKwxJCxOL6pWuRiZrFc7m8mFYt1YSjg+BI8HRwhT2K+6Zy9wpVJpuzm1B5fJlQq6-g+Sarqdr+JghOo6o+zg4bg8Xh8QIKjv6SH+fxJ5NACZQAG0GrwHFYkERdwBdTOWGx2NS3UKhH5ItcbthCURIACqVg4h-kN1FXRO2DWSiYBKSBSjKPzAaB-IAh0qprqAZDuBY-CzBw3J5EBtAgdKUE3GKSB-gBmCMkgMAvshcxoVYtw-LBa77p+txKORqHobetHkloSBKBwcBIShlGYLEa5+Isa6cdxvG3OxZJAmcFygMAQbcGIRpXKYylGjQjLSqU3LwHY0pzH4cb-NJcFAr04KUps2wthwMLAJZZlrhZXROkgzlwWqBZqeqIleQF5IIYRak7pg-mBQF7YCl26RqT+6RyoCq6Ral0Wdr0RZPsQb5zAxeE-GxqVeX4EXFeSoipAAMpgMqMGpABMZXlZ8OQwHpHBaPgamRmsVjNeVUYkWh-CqP+JAAF6YFcCCPO4kRzDQCCeWSwCmYFsJyS463kjRfi3kAA)

See the issue for details.

Comment: The ref still seems to have a wrong type. I cant pass it like

 <TextInput ref={ref} .../>

Comment: @lasJac - It appears to be a bit of a mess. I found an issue that shows how to do it though, see the edit above.